# Make auth0 express middleware not crash the server, but fail silently instead

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, authentication, jwt

I am currently working on a node project which uses auth0 for its authentication. Auth0 works with JWTs, meaning that each request to an endpoint which requires authenticatian has to be supplied with a token. auth0 supplied me with this middleware function:

```
import {auth} from 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer';
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
export const checkJwt = auth({ issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL, audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE, })
```

this is what the function looks like when its used as middleware:

```
app.post("/api/changeUserName", checkJwt, async (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    newName: (
      await  changeUserName(
        req.auth?.payload.sub as unknown as string,
        req.body.newName
      )
    )?.newName,
  });
});
```

This function works well if the jwt is valid, but if somebody makes an unauthorized request it crashes the server with following error:

```
UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized
```

How can I make this middleware fail silently? I am only familiary with middleware functions which use an input of (req,res,next) but NONE of these arguments are given at checkJWT(). How can I intercept the control flow without having access to the endpoints? I don't really understand how to wrap it.

I already tried writing my own checker but it didn't work

The error I get:

```
UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized
    at getToken (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express-oauth2-jwt-bearer/dist/index.js:83:15)
    at /home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express-oauth2-jwt-bearer/dist/index.js:353:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13) 
    at Route.dispatch (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/me/myprojectfolder/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
```

Comment: Just `catch` it from the line that's throwing? On that note, if you get an error, remember to [show the actual error](/help/how-to-ask), not just the one-liner

Comment: I am not using await in my backend, and yes it is a middleware function it works just fine https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization#configure-the-middleware but i get what you mean that is exactly what is throwing me off as well.
if i catch it, how do i call next() ?

Comment: What is the full error though? Also, remember that middleware errors tend to get forwarded as `next(err)` and end up in the global error handler, so you may in fact want to "wrap" that middelware in your own `(req, res, next) => { const result = auth(...)(req, res, (err) => { ignore the error and call next() without error argument yourself here })`.

Comment: error is too long for a comment, pls post an answer. The problem is also that i need to extract the auth object from the middleware function, else i can't access sub

Comment: Questions for more details are _never_ asking you to add those by writing a comment: [edit] your post and put this missing details in. Also I'm confused: if auth fails, auth fails. There is a no auth object to work with on auth failure. That's the whole point of the middleware failure mechanism in Express.

Comment: I added the details

Comment: yes but if I wrap their middleware, how is my req object supposed to get the auth.sub value?

Comment: Also, on a relatively important note: you're not following the pattern that https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-oauth2-jwt-bearer describes, so you may need to explain why in your post as well. As for how to pass your req: literally by passing it. The result of `auth(...)` is a middleware function with the standard middleware `(req, res, next)` signature, so you pass your `req` and `res` straight on. As for not writing an answer: your code isn't a [mcve] so I can only guess at what's wrong here, and guesses are not answers.

Comment: How am I not following the pattern. It looks same to me, although I used the auth0 docs which I linked. nevermind now i see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra middleware step after checkJwt

Here would be how to make it fail without throwing an error but you can make it do whatever you want instead

```
const unauthorizedMiddleware = (err, req, res, next,) => {
  if (err.name === "UnauthorizedError") {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
};

// routes added below this will require Auth
app.use(checkJwt)
app.use(unauthorizedMiddleware)

app.get(...
```